# How can I reinstall java when I can't find an archive for it?

Tags: re-installation

I heard about a program which allows you to make music on Linux computers called Linux Multimedia Studio. I typed `sudo apt-get install lmms` into the terminal but it responded:

```
E: The package sun-java6-jre needs to be reinstalled
```

but I can't find an archive for it.

How can I reinstall this program?

Comment: Type sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 0):

The dependency problem you have is not related to LMMS as it is written in C++, not in Java (and the lmms package doesn't need java as dependency).